# Service identification in a cloud docker system

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, identification

I got a system in Azure cloud which has a docker and each pod in the docker is a different service implemented with c# .Net Core. One of these services is a gRPC service which is a file service and every other service who want to access a file are using an SDK which access that service directly and it allows to access the requested file. The SDK is a nuget which every service adds to its references.

A flow example: Service A => invoke a method from SDK => Calls file service which access a file => return a response to the SDK => return a response to service A.

My desired behavior: I want to identify in the SDK the service itself which invokes the SDK's method. I can't use a simple input like just passing a string parameter because it's important to know the true service and I can't risk someone sending wrong information.

this is a pseudo code of what I need:

```
//this is an SDK method
public string GetSomeValueFromFile(string fileName)
{
    string invokingService = GetCurrentService();
    ...
    ...
}
```

And the question is how to implement this `GetCurrentService()` method since I have no idea where to start

Comment: Probably you could use the assembly name, sth like Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name. Or add kind of a registration/init method to your SDK, so at least one has to pass the string once and give it some thought.

Comment: Assembly name is not good since it doesn't necessarily contains a meaningful name and it can also be changed and then the authorization won't work anymore. About the registration, it sounds like you suggest getting input from the user and I can't rely on that input if they might register something with a calculated guess which can somehow give them an identification which is not truly their own

Comment: Another thought: would it be possible to give each Azure app a managed identity and read it out from the SDK, e.g. through environment variables (AZURE_CLIENT_ID)? Not sure if that would work though.